# Developing an ERP system: which platform should i select?

Tags: .net, windows, web, cross-platform, erp

We are going to develop a new ERP system (using .NET technology) that will be provided for potential clients all over the world. The system components are:

1. Stock
2. Accounting
3. Payroll
4. CRM

I want to design a reliable system, but i have been discussing that with my fiends and arguing about the technology and Platform that we should use:

- Windows or Web
- Local Storage or Cloud Storage

Of course the windows version will provide more responsiveness to the user without taking care of the client scripting  and HTTP stateless protocol. Also, the web version is platform independent (however most of the clients we are targeting use windows as an operating system).

Please, provide you suggestions and considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [presentation](http://arinsyscorp.com/downloads/ARINSYS_ERP.pptx) we show to our clients while explaining them the differences between the two.

Hope it will help you understand and explain the differences.

Also as far as your comment is concerned

> however most of the clients we are targeting use windows as an operating system.

which is true is general context as per [Net Market Share Report of Jan 2016](http://www.netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx?qprid=8&qpcustomd=0) which states the Windows:Mac ratio of ~90%:7% , but in our experience with enterprise clients this ratio changes to Windows:Mac ratio getting to ~70%:25% and 25% market share according to me is a very big thing, which i would never want to loose.

Note: Just in case you want to use an already tested framework with various clients, we are building our own API based on our experiences for developers to build custom multi tenant enterprise applications. More details can be found [here](http://arinsyscorp.com/services-solutions/products/arinsys-core/) and the nuget package can be downloaded from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Arinsys.Enterprise.Core/).

EDIT: Summarizing the key comparisons

You can opt for single page applications

> **WEB BASED SINGLE PAGE APPLICATIONS**
>
> **Pros:** Highly reduced view switching latencies giving a feel of a native application to the end user.
> **Cons:** Availability and working of features depend on the browser used by the end user.
>
> **STANDALONE VS WEB BASED**
>
> ***SYSTEM ACCESS***
>
> **Pros:**
>
> Web-based – Software is accessed from anywhere with a standard browser and an Internet connection. The user does not even have to be using his or her own computer. Most companies have reasonable Internet access so no additional costs should be incurred.
>
> Client-Server – Software is accessible through the local network, creating reasonably quick response and autonomy from the Internet.
>
> **Cons:**
>
> Web-based – Access requires an Internet connection. While access to the Internet is growing, it’s still not everywhere.
>
> Client-Server – Users must be on the local network to access the software unless the company has invested in a remote access application such as Citrix or PC Anywhere. Remote access applications require additional user software which can be expensive and increase your IT overhead.

Disclaimer: I work for [Arinsys](http://arinsyscorp.com/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11188000)

Comment: @WaiHaLee I have edited the answer accordingly, i would appreciate any suggestions for further improvements

Comment: that's a lot better. Now should the links go dead, your answer still has information of use in it.